# Getting Soft 404 error for cart page in google search console

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, google-search-console

I am getting a Soft 404 error from my checkout/cart page with opencart-latest version in Google Search Console.

I was able to place orders from the page and receive orders from it on my backend. The page appeared to be working fine.

1. Did anyone had this similar issue while using opencart, how did you fix it?
2. Should I just set up `nonidex` for that page?